# Meaning of "l'équation cesse d'être exactement vérifiée"

Tags: sens, mathématiques

In reading a math paper, I came across the following sentence:

> Si l'on remplace les dérivées et/ou primitives littérales par leurs approximations, l'équation cesse d'être exactement vérifiée.

The way I understand it, this means

> If we replace the literal derivatives and/or antiderivatives with their approximations, the equation will no longer be exactly "verified".

I am uncertain as to what "vérifiée" means in this context. The following source (regarding vérifier) does not seem to quite cover the connotation: http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/search.exe?25;s=2724010470;cat=0;m=v%82rifier;

> MATH. Vérifier une équation. Faire de cette équation une équation juste.

From context, it means that the equation will become an approximation of itself, and no longer a proper equation, but I do not know how to translate that properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, the meaning of "**vérifié**" is close to "**true**". It's a more formal way of saying true / exact.

> **Vérifier** : *satisfaire à une condition.* https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/v%C3%A9rifier/81544

Example : in math or physic, we talk about : "*l'identité est vérifiée*", "*vérifier un modèle*, "*l'équation cesse d'être vérifiée*" is a equivalent to say : "*identity is true*", "*check if the model is true*", "*equation will no longer be exactly true*".

Comment: Thanks. This is much simpler (and actually makes more sense) than the meaning I was assigning to it.

Comment: I think that a possible translation here is "no longer holds true".

Answer (score 1):

Dans ce contexte, *vérifiée* est à entendre au sens de logique mathématique comme **être vraie**.

Soit n'importe quelle équation (v.g. pas seulement des incluant des dérivées ou primitives) l'équation est dite vérifiée si le premier membre égal le second.

e.g. : X-2=0 est dite vérifiée (ou vraie) quand X=2.

Dans ton contexte, je m'imagine que tu as un genre d'équation différentielle mais qui n'est pas soluble analytiquement. Genre f(x) + f'(x) + f''(x) = blahblah.
Posée ainsi cette équation est vérifiée (vraie). Mais comme elle n'est pas soluble ainsi, tu as procédé à une simplification en pratiquant un genre de développement limité.
Cette simplification, pour donner un résultat approché du premier membre, rend l'équation formellement fausse. Le premier membre égal le second ? non! L'équation n'est plus formellement vraie. Elle n'est plus **vérifiée**.

Edit : Pardon à Victor qui a été plus rapide, je n'avais pas vu sa contribution très juste.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Victor's answer helps me directly with the translation I was working on, so I have selected it, but there is certainly no need to apologize here (I realize that you are not apologizing to me, but still).